# Find tuple in list with same first item and return another list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like this in Python:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'),('d','f')]
```

and I want join items that have same first item and result like this:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'),('d','f')]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Also your input appears to be a string, not a list (it wouldn't be valid syntactically as a list).

Comment: Are `d` and `f` supposed to be `'d'` and `'f'`? Is the inner type tuple (as you're written) or lists (as per the title)?

Comment: edit it again :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner ohk, I just edited on best anticipated thing, as you see if a b c are string and the way he wrote d and e, surely means he wanted them to be string too, rather than being a variable name.

Comment: @PatrikArtner Also most of the newbie users do the same mistake. Although I agree on your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. For efficiency, we build a `dict` with the first value as key. We keep the values in the order in which they appear (and the tuples in their original order as well, if you use Python >= 3.7 - otherwise you will have to use a `collections.OrderedDict`)

```
def join_by_first(sequences):
    out = {}
    for seq in sequences:
        try:
            out[seq[0]].extend(seq[1:])
        except KeyError:
            out[seq[0]] = list(seq)
    return [tuple(values) for values in out.values()]

join_by_first([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'),('d','f')])
# [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit `tuples` - the are immuteable. You can use `lists` and convert all back to `tuples` afterward:

```
data = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'),('d','f')]

new_data = []


for d in data                                             # loop over your data
    if new_data and new_data[-1][0] == d[0]:              # if something in new_data and 1st
        new_data[-1].extend(d[1:])                        # ones are identical: extend
    else:
        new_data.append( [a for a in d] )                 # not same/nothing in: add items

print(new_data)                   # all are lists

new_data = [tuple(x) for x in new_data]
print(new_data)                   # all are tuples again
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'f']]     # all are lists
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'f')]     # all are tuples again
```

See [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the simplest solution is to build a dictionary in which:

- keys are the first items in the tuples
- values are lists comporting all second items from the tuples

Once we have that we can then build the output list:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def merge(pairs):
    mapping = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in pairs:
        mapping[k].append(v)
    return [(k, *v) for k, v in mapping.items()]

pairs = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'),('d','f')]
print(merge(pairs))
```

This outputs:

```py
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'f')]
```

This solution is in **O(n)** as we only iterate two times over each item from `pairs`.